# Did not receive any emails using phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am not receiving any emails, please take a look at my code and correct my mistakes in the "phpMailer sections". If I can't set this up, then I can't set up smtp.

PHPmailer folder is in another directory and is perfectly connected from the includes/initialize directory.

```
<?php require_once("../includes/initialize.php"); ?>
<?php if ($session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to('loggedin.php'); }?>
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
?>
<?php $timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time()); ?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $first_name     =    $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name      =    $_POST['last_name'];
    $mobile         =    $_POST['mobile_number'];
    $email          =    $_POST['email_address'];
    $username       =    $_POST['username'];
    $password       =    $_POST['password'];
    $cpassword      =    $_POST['confirm_password'];

    $token = 'vfjhvbkebecbjDRCWVJEcbkrvlnke24t@r7c_!+#%vbejw(968';
    $token = str_shuffle($token);
    $token = substr($token, 0, 10);
    //some contents removed     

    $customer = new Customer_reg();
    $customer->first_name       = $first_name;
    $customer->last_name        = $last_name;
    $customer->email_address    = $email;
    $customer->username         = $username;
    $customer->password         = $password;
    $customer->mobile_number    = $mobile;
    $customer->emailConfirm     = 0;
    $customer->created_at       = $timestamp;
    $customer->updated_at       = $timestamp;
    $customer->token            = $token;
    if($customer->save()) {

    $from       = "whatever@mail.com";
    $fromName   = "something";
    $addAddress = "user@mail.com"; 
    $subject    = "Email Confirmation ".strftime("%Y", time());
    //send email
    $mail =  new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setFrom     = $from;
    $mail->addAddress($addAddress);
    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->isHTML  (true);
    $mail->Body     = "Please click the link to verify your email
    <br><br>
    <a href='http://www.mywebsite/phpEmailConfirmation/confirm.php?email=$email&token=$token>click here</a>
    ";
//code not sending any emails
    $mail->Send();
    $session->message('<div class="btn bg-success">Account created sucessfully please verify your email.</div>');
        redirect_to('login.php');
    } else {
        //failure

    }
    }
?>
```

I dont think posting the html form is needed...

Comment: `$mail->setFrom` sounds like a method.

Comment: @kerbholz it is indeed a method

Comment: @Cid Thx, I know, _I_ read [the wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial) ;)

Comment: You have no error checking or reporting in this code at all, so you can't tell what's breaking. Base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer, then at least you'll see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You've assigned variables to `setFrom` methods name instead of calling the function itself. You should have activated error messages to catch this.

```
$mail->setFrom($from, $fromName);
$mail->addAddress($addAddress);
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body     = "Please click the link to verify your email ...";
```